# Print numbers 1 to 10 group by 4

Tags: php

How can i print output like this?
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10

i had tried this code but not luck.

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    if ($i <= 4)
    {
        echo $i;    
        if ($i >= 4){
            echo'<br>';
            for($x = $i; $x<=10; $x++){
                echo $x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code output look like this.

1234
45678910

Comment: This prints 1 through 4. On fourth pass it enters the inner `if` which outputs a line break followed immediately by numbers 4 through 10. (`x` is 4 on first iteration.) The outer loop continues but never meets the `<= 4` condition so nothing else happens. It would be very good for you to study this until you understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

You need to check the value of `$i` is module by 4 or not, if then echo a break.

```
for ($i = 0; $i< 10; $i++){
    if ($i % 4 == 0)
        echo'<br>';
    echo ($i + 1)."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
}
```

Or

```
for ($i = 1; $i<= 10; $i++){
    echo $i."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    if ($i % 4 == 0)
        echo'<br>';      
}
```

**Output**

```
1  2  3  4  
5  6  7  8  
9  10
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is if the no. of elements in a row is a multiple of 4, then there's a line break.i.e for 4, 8, 12, 16...there will be line breaks.

Try this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

    echo $i;

    if ($i % 4 == 0) {

        echo "<br>"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
   echo $i.' ';    
    if ($i % 4==0){
     echo'<br>';
    }
 }
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    echo $i.' ';
    if ($i % 4 == 0)
    {
       echo'<br>';
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to just check if the number is completely divisible by 4 or not

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
   echo $i.' ';    
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
     echo'<br>';
    }
 }
?>
```

also you can find a working example here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ae6y-3749

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 10);
$chunks = array_chunk($numbers, 4);
foreach($chunks as $chunk){
   foreach ($chunk as $number){
     echo "$number "; 
   }
   echo "<br>\n";
}
```